# Detect the objects using velodyne HDL-32E

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ! I am using the LIDAR velodyne HDL-32E recently . The device was fixed on a car .
Now I can get the data from the device using package velodyne , and I need to detect the objects and terrain on the road .
So I want to know that is there any package or library can do it ?
I notice some information here :http://www.ros.org/news/robots/

said:

> Like many Urban Challenge vehicles, Marvin has a Velodyne HDL lidar and Applanix Position and Orientation System for Land Vehicles (POS-LV). Drivers for both of these are available in the utexas-art-ros-pkg applanix package and velodyne stack, respectively. **The velodyne stack also includes libraries for detecting obstacles and drive-able terrain**, as well as tools for visualizing in rviz.

Thank you ！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189083/detect-the-objects-using-velodyne-hdl-32e/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [velodyne_height_map package](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_height_map) which detects most simple obstacles fairly reliably. It does *not* handle overhead tree branches or tunnels correctly.

We used an earlier version of that algorithm for the DARPA Urban Challenge competition.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-06**:
Yes , thank you for your share ! I think I should search it by myself first  :)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-13**:
That algorithm is simple and relatively efficient. Feel free to experiment with variant approaches.